# Using SQL Union to perform complex report query that depends on increasingly more relaxed conditions

Tags: mysql, report, union

I have the following schema (part of it that pertains to the question):

```
# schema
- table
* table field

# schema
    - mods
        * Id
        * Title
        * Affiliation
        * Attended
    - modusergrades
        * ModId 
        * UserId
        * QuestionValues
        * Grade
        * Accepted
        * Comments
    - users
        * Id
        * Projects
        * Location
        * Grade 
        * TermId 
    - all
        * Email
        * FirstName
        * LastName
        * UserId
        * ModId
        * TermId
```

Once `mods` have registered for an event, they are able to attend an event (if the log in during a certain time, `Attended` will be set to 1). There, they are able to grade a certain number of `users`, say `maxUsers`. If they have graded (`QuestionValues != null && Grade != null`) less than `maxUsers`, we say that they have *started* grading, if they have graded exactly `maxUsers` we say that they have finished grading.

Now, I want to be able to differentiate between the following classes of `mods`:

- `mods` who have registered, but did not attend (i.e. `Attended` = 0)
- `mods` who have `Attended` the event but did not start grading (`Attended = 1` but `QuestionValues == null && Grade == null`)
- `mods` who have started grading but did not finish (so, they have non-null values for the above two fields less than `maxUsers`)
- `mods` who have finished grading (== `maxUsers`).

I want to be able to get an SQL query that puts all of this information in one place.

First off, *would the UNION operator be a fitting choice for this task*? If not, how might I approach this problem?

Second, and if the answer to the previous question is *yes*, here is what I have so far to get the `mods` who have successfully `graded`. Is this the right approach?

```
SELECT  m.Id, m.Title, m.Attended, a.FirstName, a.LastName, a.Email, a.TermId
FROM all a 
INNER JOIN mods m ON m.Id = a.ModId
WHERE m.Id = a.ModId 
    AND Attended = 1 
    AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM modusergrade mug
         WHERE m.Id = mug.ModId 
            AND QuestionValues IS NOT NULL 
            AND Grade IS NOT NULL 
            AND Accepted = 1) > 5

UNION

SELECT m.Id, m.Title, 'Graded' AS Attended, a.FirstName, a.LastName, a.Email, a.TermId
FROM all a
INNER JOIN mods m ON m.Id = a.ModId
WHERE m.Id = a.ModId 
    AND Attended = 1
```

**EDIT**: To make the question even clearer, here is my aim:

`Graded` would be a subset of `Started Grading`, which is a subset of `Attended`, which is a subset of `Registered`. With set notation:

`Graded ⊆ Started Grading ⊆ Attended ⊆ Registered`.

Is it possible to create an SQL UNION query that captures this behaviour? Do I need something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a `union` query for this.  You just need a `case` statement that has the hierarchical logic you are looking for.  This requires information from the `all` and `mug` tables along with summarized information from `modusergrades`.

I don't see a max questions value in the tables, so I assume it is some sort of parameter.

The query you want is something like:

```
SELECT m.Id, m.Title, m.Attended, a.FirstName, a.LastName, a.Email, a.TermId,
       (CASE WHEN m.Attended = 0 THEN 'Registered'
             WHEN mug.modid IS NULL THEN 'Attended'
             WHEN mug.numgraded < $maxcnt THEN 'Started'
             WHEN mug.numgraded = $maxcnt THEN 'Finished'
        END) as status
FROM all a INNER JOIN
     mods m
     ON m.Id = a.ModId LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT modid, COUNT(*) as numgraded
      FROM modusergrades mug
      WHERE QuestionValues is not null AND Grade is not null
      GROUP BY modid
     ) mug
     ON mug.modid = m.id
```

Comment: Amazing! I did not know that I could do a simple `case` statement with SQL. Thank you very much, this will reduce code duplication and looks much nicer than any `union` would.

Comment: One note: Could you please explain why a `left join` was necessary in the bottom query?

Comment: @user991710 . . . Because there might be no records in `modusergrades` for a given user (or at least, it seems that way reading the question).

Answer (score 1):

"Inner join" is what you are looking for.

Basically you do a select query from each table that satisfies what you are looking for in that table. (i.e. select id from mods where attended=0) and join them to find the ids that match.

[Here is an answered question with some code for you.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15767448/how-to-inner-join-two-select-queries-on-same-table)