# Inner join with two SELECT queries

Tags: sql, inner-join

I'm doing some online courses and am still very new to all this. I have two SELECT statements that work perfectly separately but when I add the INNER JOIN things just aren't working. I know I've got to be missing something so ridiculously simple but I'm just not seeing it.

`Farm_prices` column information

```
index       INTEGER NULLABLE    
date        DATE    NULLABLE    
cropType    STRING  NULLABLE    
GEO         STRING  NULLABLE    
pricePerMT  FLOAT   NULLABLE
```

`Monthly_FX` column information

```
index       INTEGER NULLABLE    
date        DATE    NULLABLE    
FXUSDCAD    FLOAT   NULLABLE
```

And the two select statements I'm trying toj join

```
SELECT * 
FROM `ibm-project-326221.IBM_project.MONTHLY_FX` 
WHERE date >= '2020-07-01'

SELECT * 
FROM `ibm-project-326221.IBM_project.farm_prices` 
WHERE cropType = 'Canola' 
  AND GEO = 'Saskatchewan' 
  AND date >= '2020-07-01'
```

Comment: What are you joining these on? Could you add the join query as well?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to inner join two select queries on same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15767448/how-to-inner-join-two-select-queries-on-same-table)

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  What key is used for joining?  And what is the query with the `JOIN` that is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, you want the FX rate for the corresponding date, so the join key should be `date`, not `index`:

```
SELECT fp.*, fx.*
FROM `ibm-project-326221.IBM_project.farm_prices` fp JOIN
     `ibm-project-326221.IBM_project.MONTHLY_FX` fx
     ON fp.date = fx.date
WHERE fp.cropType = 'Canola' AND
      fp.GEO = 'Saskatchewan' AND
      fp.date >= '2020-07-01'
```

Comment: Sorry, I spent sooo long staring at this and googling and moving different things around and trying to make it work, I'm not surprised I missed posting important information. That and I've never posted before and so new to this, so thank you for bearing with me. I'm out and about so I'll get back to my computer soon and try these suggestions and let you know how it goes.

Comment: It works perfectly!! thank you so much I don't know what the codes I was referencing were trying to do but it wasn't this. It was a code very similar to the two I posted originally and then it just had INNER JOIN between them and parethesis in different spots.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess without seeing your table schema, data or expected results, but a simple inner join would be

```
select * 
from farm_prices p 
join MONTHLY_FX m on m.index=p.index
where p.cropType = 'Canola' 
and p.GEO = 'Saskatchewan' 
and p.date >= '2020-07-01'
```